# Omit name of label in cref and crefrange

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to use something like `\crefrange{ref1}{ref2}` where `ref1` and `ref2` are arguments of `\label` statements for equations numbered `1` and `5`, respectively. But instead of showing `equations (1) to (5)`, I would like to show only: `(1) to (5)`.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The `cleveref` package provides the `\labelcref` macro, which acts just like `\cref` except that the name of the counter of the objects being cross-referenced is omitted.

Note that whereas the arguments of `\cref` needn't all refer to the same counter, that's not true for the `\labelcref` (as well as for `\crefrange`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{ref1} % short-hand method
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{ref2}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{ref3}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{ref4}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{ref5}

\obeylines % just for this example
\crefrange{ref1}{ref5}
\cref{ref1,ref5,ref4,ref3,ref2}      % arguments needn't be sorted
\labelcref{ref1,ref5,ref4,ref3,ref2} % ditto
\end{document}
```